# Delphi VCL code found a strange problem in Win11, set the pixel format to 8bit (index format), there was a display problem

Tags: delphi, pascal

Delphi VCL code found a strange problem in Win11, set the pixel format to 8bit (index format), there was a display problem, the code is:
Image1.Picture.Bitmap.PixelFormat:=pf8bit;

The displayed effect is like this:

[image]

After testing, this problem only occurs in Win11, and the same problem occurs in Delphi 11.3 and older versions.

Comment: Maybe it is related to your graphic card/graphic driver and not to Win11?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tested this problem on multiple Win11 devices, and I have determined that it has nothing to do with the driver

Comment: I found that this problem will occur on Win11 (22H2) computers, but there is no problem in Win11 (21H2)

Comment: Please add the info from your last comment above to the question where it belongs. Find the `Edit` button beneath the tags of your question.